# How do I beginDialog for a specific LUIS intent?

Tags: azure, android-intent, botframework, azure-language-understanding

Here's my code:

```
 async dispatchToTopIntentAsync(context, intent, recognizerResult) {
         console.log(context);
         switch (intent) {
             case 'INeedInsurance':{ 
                 const bookingDetails={};
                  bookingDetails.type="Auto"; 
                return await context.beginDialog(ConfirmAuto)

             }

             default:
                 console.log(`Dispatch unrecognized intent: ${ intent }.`);
                 await context.sendActivity(`Dispatch unrecognized intent: ${ intent }.`);
                 // await next();
                 break;
         } 
     }
```

I need to push waterfall dialog according to the LUIS Intent Result ? 
Could you help me guys?

Answer (score 1):

Try with session.replaceDialog instead of context.beginDialog and no need to return await, just follow the example in the link:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/nodejs/bot-builder-nodejs-dialog-replace?view=azure-bot-service-3.0

**Edit:**

Can you also check

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/nodejs/bot-builder-nodejs-recognize-intent-luis?view=azure-bot-service-3.0

on how to react on LUIS intents? More exactly on

```
// Make sure you add code to validate these fields
var luisAppId = process.env.LuisAppId;
var luisAPIKey = process.env.LuisAPIKey;
var luisAPIHostName = process.env.LuisAPIHostName || 'westus.api.cognitive.microsoft.com';

const LuisModelUrl = 'https://' + luisAPIHostName + '/luis/v2.0/apps/' + luisAppId + '?subscription-key=' + luisAPIKey;

// Create a recognizer that gets intents from LUIS, and add it to the bot
var recognizer = new builder.LuisRecognizer(LuisModelUrl);
bot.recognizer(recognizer);

// Add a dialog for each intent that the LUIS app recognizes.
// See https://learn.microsoft.com/bot-framework/nodejs/bot-builder-nodejs-recognize-intent-luis 
bot.dialog('GreetingDialog',
    (session) => {
        session.send('You reached the Greeting intent. You said \'%s\'.', session.message.text);
        session.endDialog();
    }
).triggerAction({
    matches: 'Greeting'
})

bot.dialog('HelpDialog',
    (session) => {
        session.send('You reached the Help intent. You said \'%s\'.', session.message.text);
        session.endDialog();
    }
).triggerAction({
    matches: 'Help'
})

bot.dialog('CancelDialog',
    (session) => {
        session.send('You reached the Cancel intent. You said \'%s\'.', session.message.text);
        session.endDialog();
    }
).triggerAction({
    matches: 'Cancel'
})
```

Comment: Can you help me >  I am facing session not found issue , Can you connect our system ?

Comment: edited my answer, this way you can do different actions based on intents more elegantly than a switch and also have the session object

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried just removing `return`? It should work. Below is an example from one of my bots, works fine. You also don't need the {} around the case, though I'm not sure that is causing your problem.

I also noticed also you're not creating a separate dialog context. I honestly don't know if that is required, I picked it up from the example. So when I pass in context to dispatchToTopIntentAsync, I'm then creating dialog context via `const dc = await this.dialogs.createContext(context);` before I get into the case statement. But I'm also using an older version of the Dispatch Bot template. Regardless, I starting the dialog as follows should be the same either way.

```js
switch (intent) {
    case VIEW_ORDER_INTENT:
        await dc.beginDialog(VIEW_ORDER_DIALOG,recognizerResult);
        break;
    default:
        var processResult = await this.qnaDialog.processAsync(userDialog.qnaState, 
        context.activity);
        userDialog.qnaState = processResult[0];
        await this.userDialogStateAccessor.set(context,userDialog);
        var output = processResult[1];
        var result = processResult[2];
        await dc.context.sendActivity(output);      
        break;
}
```

Another note, it looks like you're defining bookingDetails only in the dispatch function. This won't be available to your dialog nor will the object get updated when your dialog completes. You can pass the object as a second parameter in beginDialog and you can have the dialog return a result. You should be able to accomplish this via `bookingDetails = await context.beginDialog(ConfirmAuto,bookingDetails);`. Note though that you're only awaiting "beginDialog", so that variable is going to be pending until the dialog completes.

Comment: this.dialogs.createContext is not the function  =>>> error => help me bro

Comment: this.dialogs is a dialog set, I can walk you through my whole setup, but first I'd maybe try forgetting creating a separate dialog context and just use `await context.beginDialog(...` instead of `await dc.beginDialog(...`. Sounds like your template isn't using DialogSet or at least is calling it something different. Feel free to add or message me additional code and I'll take a look.

Comment: calling water fall dialog works fine but  continue execution of dialog failed . Error like  "  [onTurnError]: Error: DialogContext.continue(): Can't continue dialog. A dialog with an id of 'confirmDialog' wasn't found. "

Comment: Make sure the Dialog ID matches your dialog name. I define a separate variable so I have three statements (using yourDialog.js since I'm not sure anymore exactly what the dialog name is for you): `const { YourDialog } = require('../dialogs/yourDialog');`, then dialog ID variable (optional) `const YOUR_DIALOG = 'yourDialog';` and then reference that variable in the dialog call `await context.beginDialog(YOUR_DIALOG);`

Answer (score 0):

```
Import {DialogSet} from 'bot-builder-dialogs'; 
const { ConfirmHome } = require("../dialogs/confirmHome");

    //clear old dialog stack 
     const dialogs = new DialogSet(this.dialogState); 
        const dc = await dialogs.createContext(context); 
        await dc.endDialog(); 
    //end  

    //run() dialog context 
       const home = new ConfirmHome(); 
              await home.run(
                context,
                this.dialogState
              );
```